# Managing SharePoint Document Lists

Tags: sharepoint-2007, permissions, document-library

I have created a couple of Document Lists on our SharePoint 2007 portal. I then checked in the page and submitted for approval. The approver aproved the change. However, all the previously created document lists have a drop down list for each uploaded document with options like: `View Properties, Edit Properties, Manage Persmissions etc`. But the one I created does not have that drop down list when you hover over the documents. The person who approved the change is not able to see those options either. I am pulling my hair on this one.

Answer (score 0):

A custom permission set may have been applied. Can you also not delete the list? If you go into the document list, do you have the settings option?

If possible, ask someone with Site Collection Administrator or Farm Administrator permissions to log in and view the permissions on the new list. This should reveal if there is something out-of-whack with that list. If it's inheriting permissions from the parent and all the other lists are as well, and you have access to the other lists but not this one, well...this just shouldn't happen.

Can you find out what list permissions look like?